# Telegram bot faq php

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

How to do this:

```
bot: Enter your name
i: myname
bot: Enter your surname
i: mysurname
bot: Enter your question
i: myquestion
bot: enter file
i: photo||audio||video or skip
bot: thank you
```

there are examples? I did not find what I need.

Comment: figured out. closed.

Comment: use a `ConversationHandler`